# Get a response in chunks from express in browser

Tags: javascript, express, xmlhttprequest, fetch, long-polling

I'm building a progress bar for some long-running server-side tasks (up to a few minutes), and I'd like a way to display the progress of the task. I could use WebSockets or poll on intervals, but I don't want to keep track of each task. Instead, I'd like to use long-polling and write progress updates to the stream.

Here is a demo of what the route should look like on the server

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    let num = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(() => res.write(num++ + ' '), 300);
    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(interval);
        res.send();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Doing cURL on that endpoint with `-N` works perfectly, however, I'm having some issues when it comes to implementing this in the browser.

I tried with fetch like this:

```
const response = await fetch(url);
const reader = response.body.getReader();
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
while (true) {
    const { done, value } = await reader.read();
        if (done)
            break;  
    console.log(decoder.decode(value));
}
```

This worked just dandy on Chrome, but not on firefox and as you can see, it's not supported here:

https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_windoworworkerglobalscope_fetch_streaming_response_body

However, I tried a different approach, this time with XHR

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("GET", url)
xhr.onprogress = function () {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
```

This works perfectly in Firefox, but in Chrome, the onProgress event only fires after the entire request has been processed. I've also tried with `onReadyStateChange`, but that results in the same problem.

**>_<** How do I read this gosh darn data in chunks as it updates in either browser? I guess I could try Axios, but do I really need this?

EDIT: One thing it might be worth mentoining is that Chrome and Firefox seem to handle the fetch behavior differently. With Chrome, I can work with the fetch object before the fetch completes, so I do

```
const response = await fetch(url);
console.log("Preflight complete, fetch is not done though");
```

but in Firefox, the console log won't execute until the fetch resolves. This is why I think I can't work with the response body in Firefox, but I can with Chrome.

Comment: Odd - fetch streaming response body seems to be working in firefox 90 - and no, I haven't messed with any flags - and according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/body) has done so since firefox 65 - what makes you think it's not working, did you try? what problems did you encounter in firefox

Comment: well, @Bravo, I tried using the fetch example and it didn't work at all. The XHR example worked fine in FF. I also tried enabling the flags, but that didn't do me any good, and this is something I need to work on not just my browser.

Comment: @Bravo I guess it depends on what you mean by "working". I haven't done tests like the OP but technically for the stream to fire only ONE event after the fetch completes also "work" because you haven't lost any data.

Comment: @slebetman yes, I get all the data, but only after the server completes the request, not in subsiquent events after the creation of the request.

Comment: @SethPainter - yes, you did say that about chrome and onprogress - I was actually referring to fetch streaming response body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this GitHub issue:

https://github.com/ratpack/ratpack/issues/443#issuecomment-59621215

This is a Chrome/Webkit bug. Changing the `Content-Type` of the request from anything other than `text/plain` makes it work with `XHR` on Chrome. So if I change the server response to

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    let num = 0;
    let interval = setInterval(() => res.write(num++ + ' '), 300);
    // THIS IS A DUMB HACK TO GET CHROME TO PLAY NICE X_X
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(interval);
        res.send();
    }, 5000);
});
```

SHOCKINGLY, this also seems to fix the issue with fetch streaming in Firefox with unmodified flags. I think I'll go with the `XHR` method for now, just because it's a bit more compaitble, HOWEVER, the fetch version is significanlty easier to work with given each new chunk is processed individually.

### AHHHHHHHHH

Comment: FYI, I found that Firefox (v100.0) just needs some `content-type` set (either `text/html` or `text/plain` worked for me.  If no `content-type` is set on the response, then Firefox won't stream the data to a client reader (using the `fetch()` readable stream), but will instead withhold all the data until the response is completed.